# Online CSS compress which doesn't remove IE hacks

Tags: css, compression

Are there are CSS compressors online which do not remove any of the CSS browser hacks.

E.g: Using: [cleancss.com](http://www.cleancss.com/) it makes no difference which options I set it will always remove the `*display` for IE display inline-block hack.

```
a {
    border-radius:5px
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -moz-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but have you considered using conditional comments and separate style sheets instead of hacks? It's so much cleaner....

Comment: Why do you need to compress your css? I wouldn't think that it would save much.

Comment: @Pekka I have tried this in the past although I prefer all the related CSS togther.

Comment: @MichaelGarrison file is over 5000 lines so it saves a little and when I deploy the websites I compress the CSS to make it that little bit harder for somebody to copy by merging selectors with the same properties

Comment: it's a brease to copy minified CSS. Moreover it should be copiable. Try to use another one, maybe http://refresh-sf.com/yui/ (YUI is yumy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CSS Compressor](http://www.csscompressor.com/) and [Clean CSS](http://www.cleancss.com/) usually work for me, although I prefer to use a different stylesheet for all previous versions of internet explorer. It is usually better to keep previous browser supporting css seprately. Or keep hacks in a seprate file and appened it to the compressed css.

In your case, however, the compressors do remove `*`

I do not know any online compressors which preserve the hacks, however, I can offer workarounds.

A solution would be to use hacks on selector rather than on attribute.
Here are a couple of examples :

```css
* html #uno  { color: red } /*IE6 and below*/
*+html #dos { color: red }  /*IE7*/
```

Check here about the other hacks  available : http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

If that does not work for you another workaround,  might be a little tiresome, but before compression, add some unique value before a hack like

```css
#uno {#HACK#display:inline;}
```

and then after compression using a text editor replace all `#HACK#` with `*`

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me using your test code - http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/csscompressor

As did - http://iceyboard.no-ip.org/projects/css_compressor, http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/ and http://tools.arantius.com/css-compressor

It might be worth googling your question before you actually post it on here. I did a search for "css compressor", opened the first 6 results and found those four all compressed your code without removing any of the hacks.

stackoverflow isn't supposed to be used to ask something you're too lazy to search for yourself.

Comment: + 1 : cssdrive compressor http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/csscompressor/ is flawless.

Answer (score 1):

Any of these <strike>four</strike> five online minifiers do their work in way you satisfied

- http://www.creativyst.com/Prod/3/
- http://www.cssdrive.com/compressor/compress.php
- http://iceyboard.no-ip.org/projects/css_compressor
- http://tools.arantius.com/css-compressor
- http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/csscompressor/ (thanx to [@JFK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055987/jfk))

And also a smart tool (developed and used by russian Yandex) has both **online** and **back-end** versions

- http://css.github.com/csso/csso.html

Comment: + 1 : cssdrive compressor http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/csscompressor/ is flawless.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Devilo.us](http://devilo.us), which is based on CSSTidy. You can select exactly how much it compresses and how.

Answer (score 0):

http://css.github.com/csso/csso.html — this one worked for me. It is not only trim unused symbols, but also remove duplicate rules, and group selector if in help's make size smaller.

It is online version of following tool: https://github.com/css/csso