# Minify and Obfuscate Javascript files keeping IE hacks also

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, minify

Recently I wrote a javascript library and in that, I got to use the IE hacks for load event handler as below

```
/* for Internet Explorer */
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_win32)
  document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)><\/script>");
  var script = document.getElementById("__ie_onload");
  script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == "complete") {
      domLoaded(); // call the onload handler
    }
  };
/*@end @*/
```

And the other part of the js file includes some code related to the library and do something on load event of the page. Finally when the library work has been done, I thought to minify and obfuscate the library using online tools. I have gone through almost all the available tools but none of them minified the javascript library correctly. All of them were just ignoring this IE hack which I pasted above. Is there any way to get this IE hack in minified and obfuscate version.

I used http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/#demo and similar online tools.

Comment: For sure get rid of inline comments or use /* */ type comments, but why comments in minified anyway

Comment: Thats a script which needed in the IE browsers. Remember JS and CSS hacks for IE older versions..

Comment: If the minified script removes the /* */ hack comments, you will have to add them yourself

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852013/online-css-compress-which-doesnt-remove-ie-hacks